# Eagerload objects with has_many has_many association ANd where not all associations exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 2 models: Deal and User with a many_to_many relations and a user_deal joined table.

On the homepage i display a list of Deals. For each Deal I use inside the view n attribute that is inside the user_deal table.

How can I eager load this ?

I tried to do this:

**homepage controller**

```
def home    

    @deals = Deal.includes(:user_deals) 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # home.html.erb
      format.json { render json:  @deals }
      format.xml  { render xml:   @deals }
      # format.atom
    end

  end
end
```

**Models**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :user_deals,           dependent:  :destroy
  has_many   :users,                through:    :user_deals
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_deals          
  has_many :deals,                through: :user_deals
end

class UserDeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user,         :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  belongs_to :deal,         :foreign_key => 'deal_id'
end
```

But I feel it's not working as it's preloading things but then loading each object a second time...

```
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Deals" AND "Deals"."featured" = 't' 
  Deal Load (0.7ms)  
SELECT "Deals".* FROM "Deals" WHERE "Deals"."country" = $1 AND  "Deals"."featured" = 't' ORDER BY "Deals"."Deal_end_date" ASC

 // it seems here below to implement the preloading
UserDeal Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "user_deals".* FROM "user_Deals" WHERE "user_Deals"."Deal_id" IN (30, 339, 341, 337, 353, 31, 354, 260)

//but then it's loading things individually again  
UserDeal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 30) LIMIT 1
  UserDeal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 339) LIMIT 1
  UserDeal Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 341) LIMIT 1
  UserDeal Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 337) LIMIT 1
  UserDeal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 353) LIMIT 1
  UserDeal Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 31) LIMIT 1
  UserDeal Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 354) LIMIT 1
  UserDeal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 260) LIMIT 1
```

**My assumption of where the problem comes from (I'm not sure)**

The problem might be inside the User_deal table. It works this way: if a user participated in a deal, a new line is created with user_id = 5, deal_id= 4, number_of_participations = 6
So if the user 4 never participated in a deal 7, there is no line user_id= 4 and deal_id = 7

So on the homepage, Rails go to fetch the list of deals: deal 1, deal 2...and deal 7.
But he does not find the line where deal_7 as there is no such line.

Ideally, I should tell Rails to includes(:user_deals) but only those where inside the joined table UserDeals where user_id= current_user.id OR where the line with user_id = current_user.id does NOT exist...which I did not manager to implement anyway

but I'm a RoR rookie so I'm not sure of my ideas here above

**EDIT**

Following suggestion to try eager_load instead of includes, I get:

```
    User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 625]]
    Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
       (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "deals"."id") FROM "deals" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_deals" ON "user_deals"."deal_id" = "deals"."id" WHERE "deals"."country" = $1 AND (deal_launch_date <= '2016-05-02 17:21:59.547029' AND deal_end_date >= '2016-05-02 17:21:59.547087') AND "deals"."featured" = 't'  [["country", "France"]]
      SQL (3.0ms)  SELECT "deals"."id" AS t0_r0, "deals"."country" AS t0_r1, "deals"."title" AS t0_r2, "deals"."deal_card_edito" AS t0_r3, "deals"."twitter_msg" AS t0_r4, "deals"."image_url" AS t0_r5, "deals"."prelaunch_date" AS t0_r6, "deals"."featured" AS t0_r9, "deals"."admin_user_id" AS t0_r10, "deals"."created_at" AS t0_r11, "deals"."updated_at" AS t0_r12,........................................................................................................
"user_deals"."id" AS t1_r0, "user_deals"."user_id" AS t1_r1, "user_deals"."deal_id" AS t1_r2, "user_deals"."number_participations" AS t1_r3, "user_deals"."nb_new_clicks" AS t1_r4, "user_deals"."created_at" AS t1_r5, "user_deals"."updated_at" AS t1_r6 FROM "deals" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_deals" ON "user_deals"."deal_id" = "deals"."id" WHERE "deals"."country" = $1 AND (deal_launch_date <= '2016-05-02 17:21:59.547029' AND deal_end_date >= '2016-05-02 17:21:59.547087') AND "deals"."featured" = 't'  ORDER BY "deals"."deal_end_date" ASC  [["country", "France"]]
      UserDeal Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 30) LIMIT 1
      UserDeal Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 339) LIMIT 1
      UserDeal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 341) LIMIT 1
      UserDeal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 337) LIMIT 1
      UserDeal Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 353) LIMIT 1
      UserDeal Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 31) LIMIT 1
      UserDeal Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 354) LIMIT 1
      UserDeal Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "user_deals".* FROM "user_deals" WHERE (user_id = 625 AND deal_id = 260) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `@deals = Deal.eager_load(:user_deals)` - what do you get if you use `eager_load` instead of `includes` ?

Comment: about the same : see edit. they still load individually after

Comment: Are you sure that's the code snippet for your controller? The SQL statement that is generated seems to have a bunch of conditionals in it that aren't shown in the controller. Would you be able to post a more detailed snippet if that is indeed the case, and, if not, could you post a more detailed Deal model?

Comment: Could you post the view code in home.html.erb? It's possible there is additional loading happening there.